# Oracle Insert Into If NOT Exist

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm wirting and Pl_SQL Script to do some inserts if an condition not Exist

and its not working for me :(

this is my code

paramS in an CURSOR

```
FOR ps IN paramS LOOP
    compteur := 5;

LOOP  
        IF NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT *
            FROM carp.Table1
            WHERE FK_tab1  =ps.id_tab1
            AND DIC_TYPE = compteur
          )
            BEGIN
          INSERT
              INTO carp.Table1
                (
                  id,
                  FK_tab1,
                  DIC_TYPE
                )
                VALUES
                (
                  id.nextval ,
                  ps.id_tab1 ,
                  compteur 
                )
             END

    compteur:=compteur-1;
    commit;
    EXIT WHEN compteur <0;
 END LOOP;
END LOOP;
```

thanks in advance

Comment: PL/SQL has no `exists (implicit cursor)` construction. Perhaps you are thinking of a different RDBMS product.

Answer (score 3):

Usually I use such checking , `If not exists` doesnt work on oracle (as far as I know)

```
DECLARE 
CNT NUMBER(4);
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(1) INTO CNT
            FROM carp.Table1
            WHERE FK_tab1  =ps.id_tab1
            AND DIC_TYPE = compteur

  IF CNT = 0 THEN
INSERT
              INTO carp.Table1
                (
                  id,
                  FK_tab1,
                  DIC_TYPE
                )
                VALUES
                (
                  id.nextval ,
                  ps.id_tab1 ,
                  compteur 
                )
 End IF;    
END;
/
commit
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception

```
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM carp.Table1
    WHERE FK_tab1 = ps.id_tab1
      AND DIC_TYPE = compteur
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    INSERT INTO carp.Table1 (id, FK_tab1, DIC_TYPE)
      VALUES(id.nextval, ps.id_tab1, compteur);
    COMMIT;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid count() using:

```
DECLARE FG_EXISTS NUMBER(1);
BEGIN
      SELECT CASE  WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1
                             FROM CARP.TABLE1
                             WHERE FK_TAB1  =PS.ID_TAB1
                             AND DIC_TYPE = COMPTEUR
                             ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END INTO FG_EXISTS
       FROM DUAL;
       IF FG_EXISTS = 0 THEN INSERT ...
```